# Dealing with .mdf databases

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, multi-user

I am coding vb.net 2008 some small database-based applications. I can not decide which database management system to use that can give me the best performance (MS Access, Excel, SQL).

My application will be a multi-user database system where more than 3 will be running the software at the same time. The database may contain up to 25.000 records.

I was thinking about .MDF database but I am not sure what exactly they are! My questions about them are:
1) Is it possible to deploy this type of databases to a server so that multi users can use it at the same time(read,edit and add data)?
2) Will it give me high performance if I input about 25.000 records?

Any suggestion about this subject will help a lot.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Excel and MsAccess are non-starters for any kind of shared DB application (which event the simplest of DB applications evolve into). You should use a proper DB server (SQL Server, MySql, etc.)

Comment: so which alternatives do you suggest? I want the database be available offline to (at least at one computer)

Comment: You're trying to implement something that's going to be extremely fragile and will cause many problems with data consistency or performance. Rethink your approach - either use a local database without sharing (that gets sync'd to others periodically) or use a client-server setup (but then there's no local database).

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean exactly by a "client-server setup"?

Answer (score 2):

`.mdf` files are [Microsoft SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) databases.

In other words, they are intended to be put on a server for multiple users, and they are intended to be used with high load.
*(for SQL Server, 25.000 records and "more than 3" users is nothing)*

Compared to the alternatives you mentioned, you will definitely get the best performance with SQL Server.

Comment: Do you mean that I simply attach the .mdf file with application folder? Or they should be on a special server with special qualifications?

Comment: You need to install [SQL Server Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) *(free)* or the full version of SQL Server *(not free)* on a server. If your web is a web app, you could hypothetically use the same server that serves it, but a dedicated server would be better.

Comment: What if I buy only the disk space on a any host and uploaded the file to it, will it be possible to use the database in that case? I am using a desktop application not a web application.

Comment: No, you can't just drop the file on a server and expect it to work. You need a host which explicitly supports SQL Server databases. But most providers won't let you access the database directly from the web, so you need to write a web service which runs on the same host and accesses the database, and your client apps deal with the web service only. BTW, this is valid for all hosted databases, not just SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful.